# Rails 6/Webpack unable to compile images referenced from js.erb in production? (but working in development)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, webpack, dev-to-production

While working in development, I have no problem (after running `bundle exec rails webpacker:install:erb`) with this code in Rails 6 using Webpack:

```
# app/javascript/raty.js.erb

<% helpers = ActionController::Base.helpers %>

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", () => {
  $('.star-rating').raty({
    starOn: "<%= helpers.asset_pack_path('media/images/star-on.png') %>",
    starOff: "<%= helpers.asset_pack_path('media/images/star-off.png') %>",
    readOnly: true,
    score: function () {
    return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }
  });
});
```

Bear in mind I'm using Webpack to load static assets as well, so no sprockets whatsoever (although I haven't removed its gems or touched any config related to the asset pipeline; just ignoring it for the time being).
That means I'm storing all my images in `app/javascript/images`, and then requiring as per the documentation:

```
# app/javascript/packs/application.js

// Uncomment to copy all static images under ../images to the output folder and reference
// them with the image_pack_tag helper in views (e.g <%= image_pack_tag 'rails.png' %>)
// or the `imagePath` JavaScript helper below.
//
const images = require.context('../images', true)
const imagePath = (name) => images(name, true)
```

**In production, however,** my push gets rejected from Heroku because the .pngs referenced (star-on.png and star-off.png) can't be found, since (I think) Webpack compiles them into the `/public` directory, so they are not present anymore in the `/media/images` path.
Unfortunately, the guides on Heroku don't cover Rails 6/Webpack, and all the answers I've come across were meant for Sprockets, and not Webpack.

Any advice would be very much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Webpack-land, you "import" images too. Given the following directory structure:

```
app/
  javascript/
    images/
      star-on.png
      star-off.png
    packs/
      application.js
    raty.js
```

This is what you would do in your `raty.js`:

```js
import $ from 'jquery'
import 'raty-js'

import starOn from "./images/star-on.png"
import starOff from "./images/star-off.png"

$(document).on("turbolinks:load", () => {
  $('.star-rating').raty({
    readOnly: true,
    starOn: starOn,
    starOff: starOff,
    score() {
      return $(this).attr('data-score');
    }
  });
});
```

Note there's no need to use ERB here; the default Webpacker configuration will know how to resolve the output path to the image assuming you have the correct import path.

Also, you only need the following:

```
const images = require.context('../images', true)
// ...
```

if you want reference images via `image_pack_tag` in your HTML templates. You may very well want to do that, but, if just for this small example, it's unnecessary.

Comment: This worked perfectly! Thank you so much for taking the time :) By the way, where could I find this information on webpacker? I couldn't find anything like this in Webpacker's documentation...